# How to align nodes in multiple \tikzpictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{tufte-latex}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section{Some variables to play with}


\subsection{Time}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[place/.style={circle,draw=gray,fill=gray,very thick}]

                \sffamily

                % put points on graph  
                \node (n1) at (1,0) [place,label=below:{Alternate past}] {};
                \node (n2) at (3,0) [place,label=below:{Present}] {};
                \node (n3) at (5,0) [place,label=below:{Near future}] {};
                \node (n4) at (7,0) [place,label=below:{Far future}] {};


                % \foreach \x [evaluate={\y=int(\x+1);}] in {1,...,9}
                \draw[gray,very thick] (1,0) -- (7,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}



    \subsection{Hard vs. soft SF}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[place/.style={circle,draw=gray,fill=gray,very thick}]

                \sffamily

                % put points on graph  
                \node (n1) at (1,0) [place,label=below:{2001}] {};
                \node (n2) at (3,0) [place,label=below:{Alien}] {};
                \node (n3) at (5,0) [place,label=below:{Blade Runner}] {};
                \node (n4) at (7,0) [place,label=below:{WOTW}] {};


                % \foreach \x [evaluate={\y=int(\x+1);}] in {1,...,9}
                \draw[gray,very thick] (1,0) -- (7,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \subsection{Optimism vs. pessimism}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[place/.style={circle,draw=gray,fill=gray,very thick}]

                \sffamily

                % put points on graph  
                \node (n1) at (1,0) [place,label=below:{Star Trek}] {};
                \node (n2) at (3,0) [place,label=below:{Neutron Star}] {};
                \node (n3) at (5,0) [place,label=below:{WOTW}] {};
                \node (n4) at (7,0) [place,label=below:{New Rose Hotel}] {};


                % \foreach \x [evaluate={\y=int(\x+1);}] in {1,...,9}
                \draw[gray,very thick] (1,0) -- (7,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this result:
[image: sf_spectra_test]

I want to align the three continua so that the nodes are lined up with each other. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: There is no class called `tufte-latex`, did you mean `tufte-book`? Try `every label/.style={text width=3cm,align=center}`

Comment: I actually meant `tufte-handout'. That solution worked. Happy to accept a formal answer if you want the credit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for this is of course that the leftmost labels have different widths. Hence, a workaround is to set the `text width` of all the labels to the same, with e.g.

```
every label/.style={text width=3cm,align=center}
```

The `3cm` may have to be adjusted, depending on the labels themselves.

---

Addendum: strictly speaking, you only need to do this for the leftmost node, as AboAmmar points out in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366605/586).

Hence, you could just modify your code to have, e.g. for the first diagram,

```
label={[text width=3cm,align=center]below:Alternate past}
```

Or, for the code I posted below, remove the `text width=3cm,align=center` from the `widelabels` style, and use `\node [place,"Alternate past" {widelabels,text width=3cm,align=center}] (n1) {};`

---

Just for fun, here is a suggestion for an alternative approach to drawing such things, using the `chains` and `quotes` libraries. With `chains` you can get automatic positioning and joining of the nodes, and the `quotes` library provides an alternative method for adding labels.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  place/.style={circle,draw=gray,fill=gray,very thick,on chain,join},
  widelabels/.style={below,text width=3cm,align=center,font=\sffamily},
  mychain/.style={start chain,node distance=2cm,every join/.style={gray, very thick}}
}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,chains}
\begin{document}

\section{Some variables to play with}


\subsection{Time}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mychain]

  % put points on graph  
  \node [place,"Alternate past" widelabels] (n1) {};
  \node [place,"Present" widelabels] (n2)  {};
  \node [place,"Near future" widelabels](n3)  {};
  \node [place,"Far future" widelabels](n4) {};

\end{tikzpicture}


\subsection{Hard vs. soft SF}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mychain]

  % put points on graph  
  \node [place,"2001" widelabels] (n1) {};
  \node [place,"Alien" widelabels] (n2)  {};
  \node [place,"Blade runner" widelabels](n3)  {};
  \node [place,"WOTW" widelabels](n4) {};

\end{tikzpicture}


\subsection{Optimism vs. pessimism}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mychain]

  % put points on graph  
  \node [place,"Star Trek" widelabels] (n1) {};
  \node [place,"Neutron Star" widelabels] (n2)  {};
  \node [place,"WOTW" widelabels](n3)  {};
  \node [place,"New Rose Hotel" widelabels](n4) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Torbjørn has already explained the problem and shown how to fix it - so give him the green tick. I want to suggest an approach that is easier to read and maintain: use a macro for the `tikzpicture` environments.

Here is a more compact version of your MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tikz}

%usage: \linegraph{item1,item2, ...}
\newcommand\linegraph[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[place/.style={circle,draw=gray,fill=gray,very thick, radius=1mm},
                        every label/.style={text width=3cm,align=center}
                        ]
        \foreach \word [count=\x, remember=\x as \lastx] in {#1} {
                \node (n\x) at (2*\x-1,0) [place,label=below:{\word}] {};
        }
        \draw[gray,very thick] (1,0) -- (2*\lastx-1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}

\section{Some variables to play with}

    \subsection{Time}

    \linegraph{Alternate past, Present, Near future, Far future}

    \subsection{Hard vs. soft SF}

    \linegraph{2001, Alien, Blade runner, WOTW}

    \subsection{Optimism vs. pessimism}

    \linegraph{Star Trek, Neutron Star, WOTW, New Rose Hotel}

\end{document}
```

I have put node labels `n1`, `n2`, .., etc into `\linegraph` but as currently written they should be dropped because they are not used. Also, `\linegraph` will accept any number of items - up to the page width of course. The output is the same as above:

[image]

Of course, you could do something similar using chains as Torbjørn has done.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another easy fix is to just align the three left-most labels and every thing else will be kept intact. Use, for example, this command `\newcommand{\ALIGN}[1]{\makebox[6em]{#1}}` to align these nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section{Some variables to play with}

\subsection{Time}

\newcommand{\ALIGN}[1]{\makebox[6em]{#1}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[place/.style={circle,draw=gray,fill=gray,very thick}]
                \sffamily
                % put points on graph  
                \node (n1) at (1,0) [place,label=below:\ALIGN{Alternate past}] {};
                \node (n2) at (3,0) [place,label=below:{Present}] {};
                \node (n3) at (5,0) [place,label=below:{Near future}] {};
                \node (n4) at (7,0) [place,label=below:{Far future}] {};

                \draw[gray,very thick] (1,0) -- (7,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \subsection{Hard vs. soft SF}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[place/.style={circle,draw=gray,fill=gray,very thick}]
                \sffamily
                % put points on graph  
                \node (n1) at (1,0) [place,label=below:\ALIGN{2001}] {};
                \node (n2) at (3,0) [place,label=below:{Alien}] {};
                \node (n3) at (5,0) [place,label=below:{Blade Runner}] {};
                \node (n4) at (7,0) [place,label=below:{WOTW}] {};

                \draw[gray,very thick] (1,0) -- (7,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \subsection{Optimism vs. pessimism}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[place/.style={circle,draw=gray,fill=gray,very thick}]
                \sffamily
                % put points on graph  
                \node (n1) at (1,0) [place,label=below:\ALIGN{Star Trek}] {};
                \node (n2) at (3,0) [place,label=below:{Neutron Star}] {};
                \node (n3) at (5,0) [place,label=below:{WOTW}] {};
                \node (n4) at (7,0) [place,label=below:{New Rose Hotel}] {};

                \draw[gray,very thick] (1,0) -- (7,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]